# How do you construct Entity Framework Core IdentityDbContext<> outside of a service?

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, entity-framework-core

I was curious as generally you can do this WITHOUT IdentityDbContext:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
             //I am using Postgres but will also accept answers to SQL Server as I want both ultimately
              optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Database=someDb;Username=user;Password=yeah");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I go to the 'IdentityDbContext<(POCOUser)>' my OnConfiguring method disappears.  And it appears this is really not wired up anymore except if I am starting up a service and doing something similar to the Startup of:

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(cfg =>
{
    cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
});
```

That's great if I am doing a service and the EF Core is in the same contained project.  But what if I am not?  Are you not able to specify the connection string on the fly in a constructor or other method on instantiation?

Answer (score 0):

- appsettings.json - add connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeDatabase": "Host=localhost;Database=...;Username=...;Password=..."
  }
 }
```

- Update Startup.cs

  ```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services
          .AddMvc()
          .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
          .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

      services
          .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
          .AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeDatabase")))
          .BuildServiceProvider();
  }
  ```
- Inject into controller:

  ```
  private SomeContext _db;
  public SomeController(SomeContext someContext)
  {
      _db = someContext;
  }
  ```